# Android App initial release date

Tags: applications, google-play-store

When you are viewing an app in Google Play store, it displays the following : Updated, Size, Installs, Current Version, Requires Android, and Rating.

I am trying to do some research and figure out the initial release / publish dates of different apps. Is there a way to get this information from Google Play, or perhaps a website with this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check in [www.appbrain.com](http://www.appbrain.com/) for Android apps. It shows all possible information about app. Moreover, it shows release dates with respective released version numbers and number of downloads.

Comment: this is not showing the latest and accurate info.

Comment: This answer no longer seems relevant.  They don't appear to offer arbitrary app details on that site anymore.

Answer (score 3):

May be not NO!

But if you need to get this information, you need to check the comments section if there are less comments, you can analyze that the least commented DATE (or approximately) will be the initial launch date of that app.(Assuming that every developer starts giving ratings and reviews as soon as app launches to boost Downloads.)

OR

if you have access to developer console, You can check there under "current installs" section, the starting point's date on the Graph will be the Launch date of a particular App.

Also, in developer Console -> under your application -> Select Statistics -> then in the Box after "STATISTICS" heading Select "TOTAL USERS" option and then to the far right in the same line, with the option "SHOW", Select "ALL". Now in the below graph, you will be showing some pin points dropped, which indicates your respective published versions of the application/game in google play. If you hover at the first pin point on the far left of the graph, it will show "JANUARY 1: Published version 1".

Here obviously Jan 1st will be the date at which your application has come LIVE on Google play.

Respectively, you can get all the successive dates of your app updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try typing the details of the app on the search box and include the details of the previous version or release and see what Google play brings as results. I believe its possible because some people still use old phones and if they access the Google play store using their phone then Google shows the options for that OS whether its new or old.

Take for example you need to find the later version of UC browser, click on the search box and  type versions of UCbrowser or be specific;UCbrowser Cloud version for Java8.5.0.185...it all depends with the application. some you will get the later versions but for others i doubt.