# Find out when the app was created

Tags: applications, google-play-store, system-info

Is it possible to find out when the first version of an app was issued?

Google Play only shows the date of the latest update in ADDITIONAL INFORMATION field (see picture).

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to see when all the updates were issued. Probably, that's too much.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63904/android-app-initial-release-date

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks a lot! I tried several search combinations but didn't reach this page. Should I delete my question now?

Comment: If the other question does appear to answer yours, then we can mark this one as a "duplicate", which should help to increase the overall search visibility of the answers (since people may land on this one then be linked to the other).

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, I believe, it should be marked as duplicate. The other one provides a good variety of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to Google **"[name of app] version history"** and it'll find you a lot of .apk websites where you can find and download older versions of apps with the release dates and update logs. However, since what you ask is not an officially supported feature, you won't have the info you want with all apps (especially if they are old)